# JSON from API has extra characters

Tags: json

There's an API. It is and old API and I don't have much documentation for it.

When I make a GET request on a route, it returns JSON data with extra characters at the top. It looks like this:

```
)]}',

{
    //JSON DATA
}
```

Everything that appears in `//JSON DATA` is valid, but the `)]}',` is not valid.

So, what is `)]}',`?

Most likely:

1) Intentional, for some reason? If so, what is it, and how can I make JSON parsers consume it?

2) A symptom of an old, broken API?

Thanks!

Comment: If the unwanted string is 100% consistent (always the same), I'd strip it out.

Comment: This is intentional. It was a way to prevent JSON exploits. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/272471/is-json-vulnerability-still-possible#:~:text=Servers%20can%20prevent%20an%20attack,%7D'%2C%5Cn%22.

Answer (score 1):

It's not intentional for any reason I could imagine. I suspect it's broken JavaScript generation on a badly-coded Node.js-based server -- that looks strikingly like a mismatched quote in some JavaScript code that is doing hand-rolled JSON serialization.

My suggestion would be to have your JSON parser attempt to parse, and if that fails, strip out everything before the first `{`, and then attempt to parse it again.

Comment: Good call on the mismatched quote. @crowhill If this API is maintained at all, it'd be kind to let the maintainers know of this issue -- but by the sound of it, I doubt anyone is listening on their end...